# To read an xml file using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to read the below shown xml file using XSLT.I am able to read  just the first content  but not all the contents of the file .Kindly help me resolve my problem.

**XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><records><record>
<Headline>ABC</Headline>
<News_details>Date: July 7 ABCDEFGHIJK</News_details>
</record>
<record>
<Headline>DEF</Headline>
<News_details>Date: July 9  ABCDXYZ</News_details>
</record>
<record>
<Headline>GHI</Headline>
<News_details>Date: July 11 QWERTYMNBV</News_details>
</record>
</records>
```

**XSLT code:**

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <vse>
    <document url="{$crawl-url-url}">
      <content name="Headline">
        <xsl:for-each select="//Headline" />
        <xsl:value-of select="//Headline" />
      </content>
      <content name="News Details">
        <xsl:for-each select="//News_details" />
        <xsl:value-of select="//News_details" />
      </content>
    </document>
  </vse>
</xsl:template>
```

The output I get is:

```
<document url="file:///C%3a%5cUsers%5cIBM_ADMIN%5cMy%20Documents%5cSametimeFileTransfers%5csamplenews.xml"><content name="Headline">ABC</content><content name="News Details">Date: July 7 ABCDEFGHIJK</content></document>
```

Comment: No, you wouldn't get that output given the shown XML input and XSLT.

Comment: Suggestions: (1) Show what you actually **do** get; (2) show what you *expect* to get; (3) put something in your `xsl:for-each` loops -- they're empty.

Comment: The output I get is :

Comment: <document url="file:///C%3a%5cUsers%5cIBM_ADMIN%5cMy%20Documents%5cSametimeFileTransfers%5csamplenews.xml"><content name="Headline">ABC</content><content name="News Details">Date: July 7 ABCDEFGHIJK</content></document>

Comment: I need to get the other two Headlines and their corresponding News_Details i.e Headlines DEF and GHI

Comment: @RohitShetty Please edit your question and add the exact output that you want to get **as code**.

Answer (score -1):

The below XSLT will give you desired result.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:foo="http://www.foo.org/" xmlns:bar="http://www.bar.org">
<xsl:template match="/">
<vse>
    <document>  
 <xsl:for-each select="/*[local-name()='records']/*[local-name()='record']" >   
      <content name="Headline">       
        <xsl:value-of select="/*[local-name()='records']/*[local-name()='record']/*[local-name()='Headline']" />            
      </content>
      <content name="News_details">   
        <xsl:value-of select="/*[local-name()='records']/*[local-name()='record']/*[local-name()='News_details']" />    
      </content>
    </xsl:for-each>
    </document>
  </vse>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Basically you need to do for-each on record because you will the code there, and if you don't want that loop separately and you will get the list. Use the link to verify if it works or not "http://www.freeformatter.com/xsl-transformer.html"